# Need to show first day of month as "1 Sep" for Month view in Dev Express Xamarin Form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, devexpress

I need to show first day of month as "1 Sep" for Scheduler control of Dev Express. currently I am able to show "1 Sep" on month view but it is reflected for all first day of month on View. Please help me out if anyone have solution.

Comment: please read [ask] before posting.  You have not included any relevant code illustrating what you are doing or what specific problems you having.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.